# Use div tag like iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

> [image]

I want to load different (about.html, home.html, pics...) HTML pages from my web directory into the `<div id="content">` by clicking links in the navigation `<div id="content">`.

How can this be done? I'm new to CSS/HTML. I do not want to use `iframe`.

Comment: you can use jQuery and its function `.load()`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

jQuery

```
$("#nav a").on( "click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default event, so it doesn't actually go to that page.
  var url = $(this).attr("href"); // this should be some-page.html in this example.

  $("#content").load( url ); // where we're adding the new html.

});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="some-page.html">Some page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and

Also include:

```
<div id="content">
    content will be loaded here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) and its function **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**, like so:

**HTML**

```
<span data-url="somepage.html" class="link">link 1</span>
<span data-url="somepage2.html" class="link">link 2</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".link").click(function(){

    $("#content").load($(this).data('url'));

});
```

Comment: You might want to mention `event.preventDefault()` as well ;-) - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ (If you're using anchor tags.)

Comment: @NickR since I used spans I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @ Daniel, would you be so kind to give me an exmaple with concrete values.... I failed to implement your solution :( (3 days HTML/CSS exp.)

Comment: @PointerNullException here: http://pastebin.com/ijFfMrd4 Just change the `data-url` values on the links.

Comment: @PointerNullException you can just paste the code in the link above to an empty .html file and you should be good to go.

Comment: @PointerNullException let me know if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: @DanielLisik Hi, I've created 2 html tets pages "test1.html" (both with a body section and some text in it)  and "test2.html" in the site dir and replaced data-url="..." with their destination, for some resason it does not display the information in dov content. (tested with low sec settings, ie9, firefox22 and chrome)

Comment: @PointerNullException do you have the site online?

Comment: No, its on online. http://pastebin.com/r9r1e8fU task a look at me approach with your solution. and Replace the "somepage.html" with test.html oder test3.html

Comment: @PointerNullException did you get any errors while trying to open the pages? (press f12 and click on Console)

Comment: @DanielLisik "SCRIPT5009: "$" is undefinied"

Comment: @PointerNullException that means you didn't include the jQuery library properly. Can you try using this `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></style>` Also, *where* did you inclue the link to the jQuery library?

Comment: I've included the jquery on the "main" site, this is where the script will run to load  *.html into the dov content.

Comment: @PointerNullException well, you get the error you described when jQuery library was not successfully loaded. Show me the code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: @DanielLisik <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></style> solved the "undefined-error", everything seems to be fine, but the 2 test*.html won't load.

Comment: @PointerNullException it's very difficult to help you with that few clues. Did you copy/paste my code from pastebin or did you change anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54933/discussion-between-daniel-lisik-and-pointernullexception).

Answer (score -1):

```
   //this
    <header></header>
    <section>
     <div class="leftside"></div>
     <div class="right"></div>
     <div class="rightside"></div>
   </section>
    <footer></footer>
```

Comment: maybe you could add some explanatiopn of your code to help others who land on this page in the future?

Answer (score -2):

```
#nav{word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden;padding:5px 10px;position:relative;float:left;}
```